# Read xml file and make summation with java

Tags: java, xml

I am very new to java and xml.  I am trying to find a way to make the summation of the amount but I am not sure how to do this.  I tried a couple of things already but it didn't work.  Thanks a lot for your help.

```
for (int i = 0; i < clients.getLength(); i++) {
    Element client = (Element) clients.item(i);
    String name = client.getAttribute("name");
    NodeList transactions = client.getElementsByTagName("transaction");

    for(int j=0; j<transactions.getLength(); j++) {
            Element transaction = (Element) transactions.item(j);
            int amount = Integer.parseInt(transaction.getAttribute("amount"));

    }

    System.out.println("Client name : " +name);
    System.out.println("Sum : " );
}
```

Comment: Declare `int amount = 0` above the inner loop and do `amount = amount +  Integer.parseInt(transaction.getAttribute("amount"));` within the inner loop. Later, just `System.out.println("Sum : " + amount);`

Comment: You are right, thank you so much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
   for (int i = 0; i < clients.getLength(); i++) {
    Element client = (Element) clients.item(i);
    String name = client.getAttribute("name");
    NodeList transactions = client.getElementsByTagName("transaction");
     int sum =0;
    for(int j=0; j<transactions.getLength(); j++) {
            Element transaction = (Element) transactions.item(j);
            sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(transaction.getAttribute("amount"));

    }

    System.out.println("Client name : " +name);
    System.out.println("Sum : " + sum );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of thing is much easier with XPath (even if you have to use Java and DOM, which you probably don't).

```
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
for (int i = 0; i < clients.getLength(); i++) {
    Element client = (Element) clients.item(i);
    int sum = (int)xpath.evaluate("sum(transaction/@amount)", 
                  client, XPathConstants.NUMBER);    
    System.out.println("Client name : " + client.getAttribute("name"));
    System.out.println("Sum : " + sum );
}
```

Comment: Thank you Michael. You are right, it looks easier with Xpath ! :-)